# How do I access the developer room in Fallout 76?

Tags: fallout-76

I see a lot of talk online about the [developer room](https://www.engadget.com/2019/01/12/fallout-76-players-find-developer-room/?guccounter=1) in Fallout 76, players accessing it and finding all the unreleased weapons and armor.

Does anyone know it's location or how I access it?

The game is so broken, I assume I can just walk through a wall somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

### You don't, if you want to keep playing.

As the [article you linked](https://www.engadget.com/2019/01/12/fallout-76-players-find-developer-room/?guccounter=1) indicates, Bethesda is banning players who find a way into it.